# If $N$ follows Bernoulli distribution (e.g. balance coin toss), does $(X|N=n)$ follow a special distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

$$P[N=1]=P[N=2]=1/2$$

$$E[X|N=1]=3$$

$$Var[X|N=1]=16$$

$$E[X|N=2]=5$$

$$Var[X|N=2]=4$$

Interestingly,

$E[X]=E[E[X|N]]=2$ - the average of the conditional mean values.

What I'm curious about is if $E[X|N]$ follows a famous distribution and why $Var[X]$ wouldn't simply be the average of conditional variances given above.

Comment: Can you clarify what $X$ and $N$ are?  If $N$ is, say, the number of Heads tossed in some number of trials...what is the number of trials?  And you don't define $X$ at all...

Comment: @lulu, yes - apologies. $N$ is a discrete random variable (I was using coin toss as an example since $N$ only had 2 possible outcomes with equal probability). $X$ is another random variable.

Comment: So we know nothing about $X$ other than what is contained in those equations?  But of course those equations don't determine $X$ as a distribution (mean and variance do not determine a distribution)....so, what's the question?

Comment: That was my exact concern. I know nothing about $X$ other than the 4 conditional values that it take. I was hoping the values w.r.t. the other given information showed some recognizable pattern. It must be possible however to calculate $Var[X]$, right? I know $Var[X]=E[Var[X|N]]+Var[E[X|N]]$ but cannot understand what $E[X|N]$ and $Var[X|N]$ in general form...

Comment: As I say, mean and variance do not determine a distribution.  You can use your equation to determine the mean of $X$ (easily, as you say, that's just $4$) and the variance of $X$ (that's a little messier, but it is still doable).  But that's it.

Comment: Yes, what would be the $Var[X]$?

Comment: To compute the variance of $X$, just write it out.  For simplicity, say that $X$ is $Y$ when $N=1$ and $X$ is $Z$ when $N=2$.  Then we know that $16= \sum (y_i-3)^2p_i=\sum y_i^2p_i-6+9\implies \sum y_i^2p_i=13$.  Similar computation gives you $\sum z_j^2q_j$.  Now just expand the sum in the definition of $Var(X)$.

Comment: Note:  you really need to expand the variance calculation the way I did, or something like that, because the mean has changed.  To clarify, suppose your two conditional variances were both $0$.  Then we know that $X=3$ or $5$ each with probability $\frac 12$.  The variance of that is clearly not $0$!

Comment: Note:  my computation was sloppy, sorry.  It should read $16=\sum (y_i-3)^2p_i=\sum y_i^2p_i-6\sum y_ip_i+\sum 9p_i=\sum y_i^2p_i-6\times 3 +9=\sum y_i^2-9\implies \sum y_i^2p_i=25$

Comment: @lulu, thank you so much for your helpful insight. Three questions - when you reduce $\sum 9p_{i}$ to $9$ is it because you're taking sum of two $p_{i}$ which happen to be $\frac{1}{2}$? Is what you calculated the second moment of $X$ when $N=1$? If so would I then calculate $Var[X]$ when $N=1$ first and then $Var[X]$ when $N=2$ and then take the average of the two?

Comment: Something that's bothering me - we have to assume that $X$ is dependent on discrete variable $N$, right? If so would $X$ also have the same finitely many values as $N$ with the same $p$ for each $X=x$ as $N$?

Comment: To your first question $\sum 9p_i= 9 \sum p_i=9$ since $\sum p_i=1$.  Yes, you will then need to average $\sum (y_i-4)^2p_i$ and $\sum (z_j-4)^2q_j$.  To your second question, not following you.  $X$ is a function of $N$, true, but that doesn't mean that $X$ takes the same values as $N$.  $X$ might even be continuous...in which case my sum ought to be replaced by an integral (doesn't change much).